# Querying /policies/authenticationFlowsPolicy from Microsoft Graph Beta endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get all the policies possible for a tenant using the Microsoft Graph API.

Currently, I am running into an issue with a request to this endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/authenticationFlowsPolicy`

I am using an application registered in my tenant and have given it the necessary `Policy.ReadAll` and `Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationFlows` permission as [defined in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationflowspolicy-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions).

Here's what my API permissions look like in the Azure Portal [image: Azure Portal]

However, I get this weird error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AADB2C",
    "message": "User Authorization: Access is denied.",
    "innerError": {
      "correlationId": "42c3423b-b1a3-42ee-9868-c3d18bbe0e8b",
      "date": "2021-01-14T18:45:11",
      "request-id": "6c9015d2-e320-41b5-85cf-0199b54d1198",
      "client-request-id": "6c9015d2-e320-41b5-85cf-0199b54d1198"
    }
  }
}
```

My tenant is not a B2C tenant, so what is this?

Interesting things I've noticed:
When I use the graph explorer logged in as a global admin, I am able to query that endpoint. This is the response I get:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#policies/authenticationFlowsPolicy/$entity",
    "id": "authenticationFlowsPolicy",
    "displayName": "Authentication flows policy",
    "description": "Authentication flows policy allows modification of settings related to authentication flows in AAD tenant, such as self-service sign up configuration.",
    "selfServiceSignUp": {
        "isEnabled": false
    }
}
```

The web application I'm developing calls Microsoft graph to get an access token using the `client_credentials` `grant_type`. I use the Application ID and Application Secret to get an access token to perform these requests.

Anyone know what might be my issue, and how I could solve this? I have not been able to find a clear answer or explanation as to why this request isn't working.

Edit:

Here is what my JWT looks like for the application:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/2b13d287-fc73-46c4-9803-0c4cc0fb8707/",
  "iat": 1610670358,
  "nbf": 1610670358,
  "exp": 1610674258,
  "aio": "E2JgYDi/9NvXFY4udyr5X/xm9p/sBQA=",
  "app_displayname": "ucic-endpoint",
  "appid": "f55c9031-dec0-47c4-8d25-b61c7dd1cc48",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/2b13d287-fc73-46c4-9803-0c4cc0fb8707/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "49f39001-30d5-42cf-8754-f4d2502c4d22",
  "rh": "0.AAAAh9ITK3P8xEaYAwxMwPuHBzGQXPXA3sRHjSW2HH3RzEhSAAA.",
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationFlows",
    "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Invite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Policy.Read.All"
  ],
  "sub": "49f39001-30d5-42cf-8754-f4d2502c4d22",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "2b13d287-fc73-46c4-9803-0c4cc0fb8707",
  "uti": "YD03wmyyvUO86aVsJ4AEAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1585168975
}
```

This is what the access token looks like when I perform the request from Graph Explorer

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/2b13d287-fc73-46c4-9803-0c4cc0fb8707/",
  "iat": 1610669274,
  "nbf": 1610669274,
  "exp": 1610673174,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "acrs": [
    "urn:user:registersecurityinfo",
    "urn:microsoft:req1",
    "urn:microsoft:req2",
    "urn:microsoft:req3",
    "c1",
    "c2",
    "c3",
    "c4",
    "c5",
    "c6",
    "c7",
    "c8",
    "c9",
    "c10",
    "c11",
    "c12",
    "c13",
    "c14",
    "c15",
    "c16",
    "c17",
    "c18",
    "c19",
    "c20",
    "c21",
    "c22",
    "c23",
    "c24",
    "c25"
  ],
  "aio": "ASQA2/8SAAAAgY7CqdLXB3yrB6Mys5jkqtPKVEgTHYgXYaeqYtBb4sY=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "Graph explorer (official site)",
  "appid": "de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "12.207.18.194",
  "name": "Administrator",
  "oid": "b2d12f10-42eb-44a7-ba56-76ed8d268055",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "10032000A881CA7C",
  "rh": "0.AAAAh9ITK3P8xEaYAwxMwPuHB7XIi9752bFIqK23SNpyUGRSAAw.",
  "scp": "Calendars.ReadWrite Chat.Read Chat.ReadBasic Contacts.ReadWrite DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All DeviceManagementManagedDevices.Read.All DeviceManagementRBAC.Read.All DeviceManagementServiceConfig.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite MailboxSettings.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All openid People.Read People.Read.All Place.Read Policy.Read.All Policy.Read.ConditionalAccess Policy.Read.PermissionGrant Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationFlows Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod Policy.ReadWrite.Authorization Policy.ReadWrite.ConditionalAccess Policy.ReadWrite.ConsentRequest Policy.ReadWrite.DeviceConfiguration Policy.ReadWrite.FeatureRollout Policy.ReadWrite.PermissionGrant Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework Presence.Read Presence.Read.All profile Reports.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite User.Export.All User.Invite.All User.ManageIdentities.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All email",
  "sub": "Hi_D6BEuypaElwi2021X5VX6HfX-PXHEdghMXtKM21Q",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "2b13d287-fc73-46c4-9803-0c4cc0fb8707",
  "unique_name": "admin@purplepandas.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "admin@purplepandas.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "rtRFD1UbsUmnTB-2DicBAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10",
    "b79fbf4d-3ef9-4689-8143-76b194e85509"
  ],
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "O1oVLPpYMLQUaf1LY5lh99yUz56LH9dOZl1IWIMKlJw"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": 1585168975
}
```

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: @CarlZhao I have udpated my post to include those JWTs. The issue though, is that my applciation doesn't use delegated permissions. It uses application permissions. Doesn't Graph Explorer use delegated permissions?

Comment: Graph Explorer uses user/password flow, and it defaults to delegate permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Involving the AADB2C error, it is definitely necessary to log in to the user, so you cannot use the daemon-based client_credentials grant_type, because it generally has no user interaction, you should use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain access token, which requires you to log in to the user and obtain the authorization code, then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

By the way, I just used the client_credentials flow to do a test. It prompts me to log in as a user. This is strange because the document states that the application permissions can be used, so I think this may be an unknown error.

In addition, calling the api also requires the user to have an administrator role:

> You must have one of the following user roles for access: External ID
> User Flow Administrator, External ID User Flow Attribute
> Administrator, External Identity Provider Administrator, Application
> Administrator, Security Administrator, Security Reader, Global Reader,
> Global Administrator.

Comment: Thanks, Carl for your help. So, basically with anything that involves AAD B2C, I can’t use the client_credentials grant flow? The thing that’s throwing me off though, is that I get an AAD B2C error even though my tenant is not even a B2C tenant.

Comment: @deathcat05  Yes, AAD B2C involves user interaction. It currently does not support client credentials flow. As for the error you encountered today, I think it is a bug, I noticed:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationflowspolicy-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions   it is  B2B function, it is a new function, and is still being updated as of today.

Comment: @deathcat05  There is a similar B2C policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/b2cauthenticationmethodspolicy-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http, which is very similar to the AAD policy. Graph api may implement this endpoint first, and then the B2C error message is carried. It may be that the developer forgot to modify the error message. I will report the error message to Microsoft, hoping that the bug will be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: How do you know that the first link is just a B2B function and that the second one is a B2C function (besides the fact that the second specifically says b2c). I'd really like to understand how you knew this so that I am able to look for these things in the future :)

Comment: @deathcat05 I clicked on the [authenticationFlowsPolic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationflowspolicy?view=graph-rest-beta) link in the document, and then went to the `authenticationFlowsPolicy resource type` page. The document pointed out:  `Represents the policy configuration of self-service sign-up experience at a tenant level that lets external users request to sign up for approval`.

Comment: Copy this paragraph to Google search, you will see the [B2B feature introduction document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-overview).